Setting config values for integration tests
I've been trying to set config values both through config-global.php and using Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface but it appears this isn't working.
I'm aware of Issue #39230 on the Magento 2 github but I haven't seen any workarounds posted for this issue and I've been struggling to figure out one myself.
Anyone out there who has come up with a workaround?
